# Javascript Regex to find a exact match for a word begining with dot

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, pattern `\bvalue\b` lists all "value" in exmaple following:

```
value is a property of textbox object. Using textbox.value, we can get or set value property of textbox.
```

`\bvalue\b` will return 3 matches for above string while I want to return 2 matches that don't have dot precede (textbox.value).
What is useful pattern to solve my problem?

Comment: only dot or any other non word? like `text!value` do you want to match it?

Comment: Currently I met problem with dot. I can also meet the same problem with other special characters such as commas(,), exclamation(!)...  later. It's wonderful to get the pattern to avoid some special characters listed preceded "value"

Comment: Ohh... In that case..Check my answer...

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solutions will be to match:

```
(^|\s)value(\s|$)
```

And use [`str.trim()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) on the resultant string.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kI5nI6/4)

Answer (score 1):

This will give the matches that don't have a preceding dot.

```
\b(^|[^.])value\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wR2mD5/2)

Comment: Thank for your comment! It ran with substitution "$1replacement" perfectly when replacing. That's enough for me. Can you show me the solution without using $1 in replacement ?